# Solidus Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, spree

So I want Solidus with the Bootstrap framework.

On the Solidus's Github page: https://github.com/solidusio/solidus I see the following dependencies:

- solidus_frontend (Cart and storefront)
- solidus_backend (Admin area)

Is it possible to exchange those with those:

- spree_frontend
- spree_backend

Until Solidus provides a Bootstrap option? because I noticed from https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/580 that there might be a Bootstrap Solidus.

Any help or input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option for the frontend would be to take the 200 creative bootstrap frontend from here: https://github.com/200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend and port it to solidus.

As it was for 2.4, so it should be a reasonably straight forward port.

For the backend, your best bet might be to sit tight. spree_backend would take a monstrous amount of effort to get working against solidus. Meanwhile solidus_backend is undergoing very active development to bring it up to a higher standard and user experience than spree_backend on 3.0 had.

See: http://solidus.io/blog/2015/11/19/ux-roadmap-for-the-admin-interface.html and related PR's and issues for direction.